# Is there different between 'if' and 'ternary operator' in GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm practicing GLSL on ShaderToy

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord ) {

vec2 coord = fragCoord.xy/iResolution.xy;

vec3 background = vec3(1.);

vec3 axesColor = vec3(1.,0.,0.);
vec3 gridColor = vec3(0.85);

vec3 color = background;

const float tickWidth = 0.1;
for(float i = 0.0 ; i < 1.0 ; i += tickWidth)
{
    if(abs(coord.x - i) < 0.002) color = gridColor;
    if(abs(coord.y - i) < 0.002) color = gridColor;
}

if(abs(coord.x) < 0.005) color = axesColor;
**if(abs(coord.y) < 0.005) color = axesColor;**
**//color = abs(coord.y) < 0.005 ? axesColor : background;**

fragColor = vec4(color,1.0);  }
```

my question is on last 3 lines.

First, I used ternary operator for branch, but it made weird result that only drawing "x axes".

However, when I changed the operator to if, it works well. The code drew x, y axes and all grids as I wanted.

So I wonder is there different between if and ternary operation in GLSL?
If that, how can I choose correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is obvious. The ternary operator *will* return one of the two alternative values it is given; that's what it is for. An `if` condition that doesn't have an `else` block won't do anything if the condition is false.

The ternary operator version *will set* `color` to `axesColor` or `background`. But by that point in your code, you've gone past 3 other conditions that may have changed the value of `color` from its initial value of `background`. But the ternary operator doesn't care. It will *overwrite* whatever is in `color` with either `axesColor` or `background`.

What you probably wanted was `color = abs(coord.y) < 0.005 ? axesColor : color;`, so that the value will be preserved if the condition is false.

Comment: Doesn't compilers tend to compute both branches of the ternary and just discard when needed? From what I have read smart enough compilers should do the same (when not very performance intensive) with branches.

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez: That has nothing to do with the issue here. That's a matter of optimization. The OP's issue is that the `if` version specifically does something different from the `?:` version. Because they're *supposed to* do different things; the statements aren't equivalent.

Comment: Yep I am aware, just adding to the knowledge base I guess. That's why I didn't add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

for the folks that came here expecting the technical explanation, exclusive to shader execution difference between an if statement and an equivalent ternary operator, see this precise and polite explanation: https://itecnote.com/tecnote/r-shader-optimization-is-a-ternary-operator-equivalent-to-branching/